# Display the array in android

Tags: android, arrays

How to get an array items like this

["String1", "string2", "string3",.....,"Stringn"]

but if we use Arrays.toString(array) it will display like [string1, string2, string3] but i want like above.

Thnaks in advance

Comment: just use string builder and a loop to build your string.

Comment: Its woking but i used this stringBuilder in jsonString.array().value(stringBuilder).endobject(); its giving me added quotes like ["\"string1" , \" string2".....] what is the reason its show like that?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

```
private void btn3() {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    layout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    layout.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);

    tv2 = new TextView[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        tv2[i] = (TextView) new TextView(Random.this);
    }

    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        tv2[i].setLayoutParams(lparams);
        tv2[i].setText((i + 1) + " " + list.get(i));
        layout.addView(tv2[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, this makes for every array a new textview